# How to remove extra quotes in between quotes for following example "Dec 01, 1999","Pocket Aquarium “Pocker" Pocket","Random : USA","USA" using python

Tags: python, csv, data-science, data-cleaning

I want to remove extra quotes in each line of csv file.
ex:

```
 "Dec 01, 1999","Pocket Aquarium “Pocker" Pocket","Random : USA","USA"
```

ideal output required:

```
"Dec 01, 1999","Pocket Aquarium Pocker Pocket","Random : USA","USA"
```

Comment: use ```code``` (```) for better illustration.

Comment: you csv file contains extra `“` or `"` or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this:

input:

```
"Dec 01, 1999","Pocket Aquarium "Pocker" Pocket","Random : USA","USA"
```

code:

```
import csv

# reading the csv
with open('test.csv', "r+") as csvfile:
  # reading with csv object
    lines = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    modified_lines = []
    for line in lines:
        modified_lines.append([item.replace('"', "") for item in line])

    # creating a new csv with modified values
    with open("test_modified.csv", "w+") as csv_modified:
        for line in modified_lines:

            # formatting the lines
            line = ['"' + item + '"' for item in line]
            line = ",".join(line) + "\n"

            # writing modified lines
            csv_modified.write(line)
```

`test_modified.csv`

```
"Dec 01, 1999","Pocket Aquarium Pocker Pocket","Random : USA","USA"
```